# Hodge star on this expression

Tags: differential-forms

if we have $\alpha$ a complex function, and we want to take the Hodge dual of

$$d\bigg(\frac{1}{|\alpha|^2}\bigg)d(\bar{\alpha})$$ what will that give us? Can we take $$\star\bigg(\frac{1}{|\alpha|^2}\bigg)d(\bar{\alpha}) + d\bigg(\frac{1}{|\alpha|^2}\bigg)\star d(\bar{\alpha})$$ or this doesn't make sense at all?

Comment: No, it doesn't make sense. There is no Leibniz rule for $\star(\beta\wedge\gamma)$ for 1-forms $\beta$ and $\gamma$. Note, in particular, that the Hodge-star of a 2-form is an $n-2$-form (where $n$ is the real dimension of your complex manifold), whereas your purported formula is the sum of an $(n+1)$-form (which vanishes) and an $n$-form.

Comment: So there is not another way to simplify this?Other than the non-valid Leibniz rule?

Comment: See also e.g. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/605448/the-hodge-operator-and-the-wedge-product