# Identifying a wedge-to-metric formula

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request, exterior-algebra

In [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/605448/the-hodge-operator-and-the-wedge-product), the original poster wrote:

> On every Riemannian manifold $M$, we can consider the Hodge
>   $*$-operator, which is characterised by the following formula:
>   $$a\wedge *b = (a,b)\nu.$$ Here $a$ and $b$ are smooth forms on $M$,
>   $(\ ,\ )$ is a metric on $\wedge T^*\!M$ and $\nu$ is the volume form
>   with respect to the Riemannian metric.

I'm looking to study this formula in particular, but it's difficult to search for because of the notation.

What are a couple webpages or books that discuss (or even derive) this formula?  The simpler the better.

Comment: Even if this is not a direct answer to your question : intuitively, this formula can be seen as a generalization in the context of an embedded surface in $\mathbb{R}^3$ of $U \times V^* = \sin \alpha \|U\|\|V\|$ where $V^*$ is the vector directly orthogonal to V in TM and $\alpha$ the angle between $U$ and $V^*$.

Comment: @JeanMarie Would you say that this formula only applies in cases where $a$ and $b$ are forms of the same degree, like in your example?

Comment: I would say : yes because (.,.) is bound to be a bilinear or sesquilinear form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This formula appears frequently as the [definition of the Hodge star operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hodge_star_operator#Formal_definition_for_k-vectors).